# ignoring messages in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have some obj-c code, i plan to send unsupport messages in plugin. However i cant seem to ignore messages. I thought "-(id) forward: (SEL) selector: (marg_list) arglist;" would solve it but it hasnt. How do i have this app run entirely without getting a warning and a termination call?

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/Object.h>

//------- @interface section -------

@interface Fraction: Object
{
    int  numerator;
    int  denominator;
}

-(void)   print;
-(void)   setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void)   setDenominator: (int) d;
-(id)     forward: (SEL) selector: (marg_list) arglist;

@end

//------- @implementation section -------


@implementation Fraction;
-(void) print
{
    printf (" %i/%i ", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n
{
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d
{
    denominator = d;
}

-(id) forward: (SEL) selector: (marg_list) arglist
{
    return nil;
}

@end

//------- program section -------


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Fraction  *myFraction;

    // Create an instance of a Fraction

    myFraction = [Fraction alloc];
    myFraction = [myFraction init];

    // Set fraction to 1/3

    [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
    [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

    // Display the fraction using the print method

    printf ("The value of myFraction is:");
    [myFraction print];
    printf ("\n");
    [myFraction someMsg: 99];
    [myFraction free];
    printf("end");  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than handing this in the plugin, it would be best to do it in the *caller*. Instead of:

```
[myFraction someMsg: 99];
```

you should check if `myFraction` responds to the `someMsg` selector:

```
if ([myFraction respondsToSelector:@selector(someMsg:)]) {
    [myFraction someMsg: 99];
}
```

The `-respondsToSelector:` method is defined in the [NSObject Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html), so note that your `MyFraction` object needs to inherit from `NSObject`, not `Object` (or else implement the `NSObject` protocol yourself). Of course, this is really best practice anyway -- directly subclassing the `Object` class is generally discouraged.

Comment: Directly subclassing Object is more than merely discouraged... nothing actually does it on OS X or in GNUStep. NSObject and NSProxy are both root level objects. Object also does not us retain/release semantics, so passing them around into NSObject based collections and APIs will not work correctly.